# MySQL optional stored proc parameters

Tags: mysql, database

In MSSQL, when I want to ignore an empty filter parameter, I do the following

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE EmployeeName = ISNULL(@EmployeeName, EmployeeName);
```

How would I achieve this in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like I'm going to have to use dynamic SQL instead of procs, to allow for dynamic ordering, unless you could kindly suggest a way of achieving that in a mySQL stored proc.